# PostgreSQL check if Paperclip attachment exists

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to loop through my Product postgres table and then display the first 5 that have a Paperclip image attached, but none of my queries are working. In my Product model Paperclip attachments are referred to as photo_image_file, photo_file_name, photo_content_type, etc.

Here's the line of code:

```
<% featured = Product.order('created_at DESC').limit(5).where("photo_file_name?") %>
```

What's the correct PostgreSQL query to accomplish this? It just needs to return a true boolean value.

Comment: Try this: `where("photo_file_name IS NOT NULL")`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Product.where.not(photo_file_name: nil).limit(5).order(created_at: :desc)
```